# Calling 32 bit lib files from 64 bit targeted application

Tags: c++, 64-bit, static-libraries

I am writing a 64 bit targeted c++ program. I need to call commands from a 3rd party .lib file that is targeted towards a 32 bit environment, however when trying to do so I get a LNK2001 error. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not directly, no; you can't link 32-bit code into a 64-bit executable.

Perhaps you could create a separate 32-bit process to host your static lib and write a stub API in your 64-bit program that uses interprocess communication to have the 32-bit process execute the code on your behalf.

Comment: Do you know of any good examples of how to do this? Also, is it possible to pass large amounts of data from the 32 bit process to the 64 bit process?

Comment: Any IPC mechanism would work: DCOM, sockets, named pipes, shared memory, etc etc. Most of those techniques have no problems with moving large amounts of data between the two processes.

Comment: Are there any simple examples out there to teach me to write a client/server app communicating via shared memory on windows in c++?

Comment: Ok, it turns out this only requires two lines of code, problem solved... for now... HANDLE Index = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 1, "Index");
 Buffer = (unsigned char*) MapViewOfFile(Index, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 1);

Answer (score 5):

You can't do this directly within an application.

Your best option is to get a 64-bit version of the library.

If you can't do that, you can create a separate 32-bit app that acts as a mediator between your main program and the library, using sockets or pipes to communicate.